# Issues with input() and raw_input() for Python 2.7. User entered data is not read properly. What is going on?

Tags: python, python-2.7, input, raw-input

So at my company they are making me use python 2.7 because of the product for a compatibility reason that I won't get into here.

So I am writing a program that connects to a device using SSH (a switch specifically) and I am able to actually access the device using SSH and this device is ping-able on my machine. The problem ? raw_input seems to not be taking it as a string. When I try input(), it gives me an invalid syntax error.

For the scripts I write, I usually use arparse and the user enters the IP address, username, and password through the terminal, but I want this script to not use argparse and to use input() or raw_input. All my SSH scripts work good except for this one, the only one using raw_input and input() instead of argparse

```
def runMain():

    scriptName = os.path.basename(__file__)

    print("The name of this script is: " + scriptName)

    print("**************************************\n")

    print("This script allows you to enable and disable ports on the SNET or SOOBM switches, have fun ! \n")

    print("**************************************\n")

    optionPrinter_switches_top()

    user_input = raw_input("Make your selection") # This does not work if I change to input(), it exits out of the program

    if user_input == 1:
        print("You selected the SNET switch, lets proceed !")

        deviceIP = input("Enter the IP address for this device")  # I tried changing these to raw_input, I get a syntax issue
        deviceUsername = input("Enter the username for this device")
        devicePassword = input("Enter the password for this device")

        confirm_ping = canPing(deviceIP) # This is a boolean function that works correctly in every script but this one.

        if confirm_ping:
            ssh_SNET = connectToSSH_SNET(deviceIP, deviceUsername, devicePassword)
        else:
           print("Sorry, that device is not even ping-able. Figure that issue out and retry the program...")
           sys.exit(-1)

        while True:
            SNET_options()

            user_choice_SNET = input("Please select an option")

            switch_result = SNET_switch_func(user_choice_SNET)

            if switch_result == "displayInterfaceBrief":
                time.sleep(5)
                displayInterfaceBrief_SNET(ssh_SNET)
            elif switch_result == "enablePort":
                time.sleep(5)
                enablePort_SNET(ssh_SNET)
            elif switch_result == "disablePort":
                disablePort_SNET(ssh_SNET)
            elif switch_result == "switchReboot":
                reboot_SNET_switch(ssh_SNET)
            else:
                print("Exiting program now....")
                sys.exit(-1)
```

Here are relevant issues:

```
user_input = raw_input("Make your selection") # This does not work if I change to input(), it exits out of the program
```

```
 deviceIP = input("Enter the IP address for this device")  # I tried changing these to raw_input, I get a syntax issue
 deviceUsername = input("Enter the username for this device")
 devicePassword = input("Enter the password for this device")
```

```
confirm_ping = canPing(deviceIP) # This is a boolean function that works correctly in every script but this one.
```

Conclusion ? There is an issue with input()/raw_input() . What is going on here and how can I fix this ? I can't use python 3.7 and it really is frustrating. Thanks for the help

Comment: `input()` does a different thing in Python 2 from Python 3. In Python 2, `raw_input()` is the correct function to use to input a string. Why are trying to change `raw_input()` to `input()`? What's the problem with using `raw_input()`?

Comment: raw_input() returns a string. This means if user_input == 1: will always be false unless you change it to if user_input == "1": or you can change it to int(raw_input) and setup a try/except case to handle string inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `if user_input == 1:` to `if int(user_input) == 1:` as the input function takes an input in string format, by default.

And, if you want to use `input()` instead of `raw_input()` to take input from users in python 2.x, then you can try below code:

```
if hasattr(__builtins__, 'raw_input'):
    input=raw_input

user_input = input("Enter a number: ")
```

Comment: Here is my issue. This is a boolean function that works in all my other scripts: ``` def canPing(host): `` , the parameter host is my deviceIP , in which is supposed to be a str(). However, when I do type hint in the IDE, it says it is an object.It says it's an object in other scripts as well. What is going on here ?

Comment: what do you mean by  "when I do type hint in the IDE"?

Comment: @ AnubhavSingh Type hint is a feature in pyCharm that can show you what data type the variables you are using are. It says host (which the user enters as deviceIP) is an object , when it is supposed to be a string().

Comment: Thanks. then try canPing(str(deviceIP)) and by the way take input  via raw_input() not input()

Comment: If this doesn't work, then please try to add error what you are getting on changing input() to raw_input()